# MMDrawerController - navigate to another ViewController with Sidebar's UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, sidebar

I'm having some troubles with navigating between ViewControllers when tap on side-bar item.

My demand: after tap on an item on Left-Sidebar, it transitions to another ViewController and the left and right sidebars are still working

I've tried:
Case 1

```
                    ---mm_left---[NavigationController]---root---[LeftViewController]:3 items---push--- to [ViewController2] below
[MMDrawerController]---mm_center---[NavigationController]---root---[MainController]---push---[ViewController1]---push---[ViewController2]
                    ---mm_right---.....
```

tap on [LeftViewController] to transit to [ViewController2] an `use setCenterViewController: ViewController2`, a new black, full screen view appear and my [LeftViewController] becomes [ViewController1]

(put `setCenterViewController` both in `prepareForSegue` and `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`, neither of them work)

Case 2

```
                    ---mm_left---[LeftViewController]:3 items---modal--- to [ViewController2] below
[MMDrawerController]---mm_center---[NavigationController]---root---[MainController]---push---[ViewController1]---push---[ViewController2]
                    ---mm_right---.....
```

(without NavigationController on the left side, so I have to use modal to transit)

In this case, [ViewController2] did appear, without navigation bar (of course), but left and right sidebar didn't work. I tried to init a new drawerController but it had no effect.

Case 3:

```
                                                    ---mm_left---[LeftViewController]---push--- to [ViewController2] below
[NavigationController]---root---[MMDrawerController]---mm_center---[ViewController1]---push---[ViewController2]
```

This time, it doesn't cause error, but when I navigate to [ViewController2], [LeftViewController] doesn't show up (neither from tap on leftView's item nor pushing from [ViewController1]).

I used `setCenterViewController:` at several places but it doesn't solve my problem.

Help ? anyone

Comment: did you find any solution?